# Can't access MediaWiki after moving it from Apache to Nginx

Tags: nginx

Here's what I wrote on the `nginx.conf` file. There are currently two `server` categories in this file, which are Redmine and MediaWiki.

```
 38 server {
 39         listen 80;
 40         server_name wiki.mypage.com;
 41         root /var/www/html/mediawiki;
 42
 43         location / {
 44             index index.php;
 45             error_page 404 = @mediawiki;
 46         }
 47
 48         access_log /var/log/nginx/access-wiki.log;
 49         error_log /var/log/nginx/error-wiki.log;
 50
 51         charset utf-8;
 52         passenger_enabled on;
 53         client_max_body_size 50m;
 54     }
 55
 56     server {
 57         listen       80;
 58         server_name  redmine.mypage.com;
 59
 60         #charset koi8-r;
 61         charset utf-8;
 62         passenger_enabled on;
 63         client_max_body_size 50m;
 64
 65         #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
 66
 67         location / {
 68             root   /var/www/redmine/public;
 69             index  index.html index.htm;
 70         }
 71
 72         #error_page  404              /404.html;
 73
 74         # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
 75         #
 76         error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
 77         location = /50x.html {
 78             root   html;
 79         }
 80
 81         # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
 82         #
 83         #location ~ \.php$ {
 84         #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
 85         #}
 86
 87         # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
 88         #
 89         #location ~ \.php$ {
 90         #    root           html;
 91         #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
 92         #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
 93         #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
 94         #    include        fastcgi_params;
 95         #}
 96
 97         # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 98         # concurs with nginx's one
 99         #
100         #location ~ /\.ht {
101         #    deny  all;
102         #}
103     }
```

When I re-started the Nginx and tried to access each webpage (wiki.mypage.com and redmine.mypage.com), I only managed to access the redmine only.

Is there something wrong with the configuration itself, or should I be looking into other files?

Comment: Server configuration is more Server Fault than Stack Overflow but at least you have a difference in root tag

Comment: i see but which means?